# Atomic get and delete in memcached?

Tags: memcached

Is there a way to do atomic get-and-delete in memcached?

In other words, I want to get the value for a key if it exists and delete it immediately, so this value can be read once and only once.

I think this pseudocode might work, but note the caveat postscript:

```
# When setting:
SET key-0 value
SET key-ns 0

# When getting:
ns = INCR key-ns
GET key-{ns - 1}
```

Constraint: *I have millions of keys that could be accessed millions of times*, and only a small percentage will have a value set at any given time. I don't want to have to update an atomic counter for every key with every get access request as above.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical, but yet generic, answer to your question is : lock free hash table with a relaxed memory model.

The more relaxed is your memory model the more you get with a good lock free design, it's a way to get more performance out of the same chipset.

[Here is a talk about that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJ-719EGIts), I don't think that it's possible to answer to your question with a single post on hash tables and lock free programming, I'm not even trying to do that.

Comment: the key value data needs to be shared in a large distributed system, hence memcached. the setter and getter will very very likely be different machines.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with memcached in a single command since there is no api that supports exactly what your asking for. What I would do to get the behavior your looking for is to implement some sort of marking behavior to signify that another client has or hasn't read the data. For example, you could create a JSON document as follows:

`{
  "data": "value",
  "used": false
}`

When you get the item check to see if it has already been used by another client by examining the used field. If it hasn't been used then set the value using the cas you got from the GET command and make sure that the document is updated to reflect the fact that a client has already accessed this key.

If the set operation fails because the cas is invalid then this means that another client has obtained this item and already updated it in memcached to signify that it has been used. In this case you just cancel whatever you were doing with the item and move on.

If the set operation succeeds then this means you client is the sole owner of this data. You can now delete it from memcached and do whatever processing on it you like.

Note that when doing the set I would also add an expiration time of about 5 seconds. This way if you application crashes your documents will clean themselves up if you don't finish with the entire process of deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

To put some code to the answer from @mikewied, I *think* the basic gist is... (using Node.js):

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcache = new Memcached('localhost:11211');

var getOnce = function(key, callback) {
  // gets is the check-and-set get (vs regular get)
  memcache.gets(key, function(err, data) {
    if (!data) {
      // Cache miss, nothing to see here.
      callback(null);
    } else {
      var yourData = data[key];
      // Do a check-and-set to remove the data from the cache.
      // This sets the value to null *only* if no one else already did.
      memcache.cas(key, null /* new data */, data.cas, 10, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          // Check-and-set failed! (Here we'll treat it like a cache miss)
          yourData = null;
        }
        callback(yourData);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Memcached and so I may be wrong. My answer is from reading the documentation and my experience using Memcached.

#### IMO this is not possible with `memcached`'s current implementation.

to demonstrate why this is not possible currently here is a simple example to demonstrate the race condition:

- two processes start at the same time
- both execute a `get`/`delete` at the same time
- `memcached` replies to both `get` commands at the same time
- done (the desired result was to have `get`/`delete` execute atomically then the second get/delete to fail. instead `memcached` did `get`, `get`, `delete`, fails to `delete`)

to get an atomic `get`/`delete` would require:

- a new command for `memcached` that is atomic let's call it `get_delete`
- some sort of synchronization lock method of all the memcached clients to ensure both the `get` and `delete` commands are executed while the lock is held

  - so all clients would grab the synchronization lock whenever they need to enter the critcal section (i.e. `get`, `delete`) then release the lock after the critical section